# Inserting into Dynamic table with Entity Framework vb.net

Tags: vb.net, entity

i have 20 tables that looks same but every table belong to another user i have.
every table name is like tableName22
22 is the number of the user.
so for user 15 i have table that is name is tableName15.

i want to insert data for the tables but every time to insert to another table.
i can use cases

```
switch(type) {
  case "ProdA": context.tableName22.Add(data); break;
  case "ProdB": context.tableName15.Add(data); break;
  case "ProdC": context.tableName9.Add(data); break;
}
```

but in this case every time i create another user i need to update the code.
there is dynamic way to use entity and every time add to another table that his name i hold in variable of string
like this:

```
dim usernum as integer = 53
dim tablename as string = "tableName" & usernum
context.tablename.Add(data);
```

Comment: *"i have 20 tables that looks same but every table belong to another user i have"*. Well that's wrong for a start. You need to learn how to use a database. You don't create a separate table for each user. You create one table for users and then one table for the other data with a foreign key column to indicate what user record the data is related to. That's what the "relational" in relational database means. Basically, get rid of everything you have and design your database properly. If you do it properly then you just add a new row to user table, not a new table.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i know but i separate because of security. the using of users is only for example

Comment: There is no security benefit. You are just doing it wrong. Do it right.

Comment: @jmcilhinney ok. altought i wrong. there is answer to my question?

Comment: It's pointless to provide an answer to a question that should not be asked in the first place. The "answer" is to do the right thing and then your question becomes moot.

Answer (score 0):

Use my repo in Github,  it  will  give you  the option to build all  tables dynamically

https://github.com/imaa/DynamicDbContext